# Angular Inline Conditional on ng-bind

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the pageTitle to initialise to data.products[whichItem].date if condition is true or pageTitle = data.products[whichItem].valuetoday  if condition is false   is there an ng-directive more appropriate or is my syntax wrong

```
  <section ng-bind="(true) '{{pageTitle = data.products[whichItem].date | 
getYear}}' : '{{pageTitle = data.products[whichItem].valuetoday}}' " ></section>
```

Comment: notice the tagging. The angular-tag refers to angular 2 -> This is AngularJS, so should be tagged with angularjs ;)

Comment: The role of the template is to display data. Not to initialize variables. Initialize variables in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to print the `pageTitle` value or assign value to `pageTitle`.?

You can do those things in controller. `ng-bind` is only to print the value in page

```
$scope.setPageTitle(data,itemIndex){
$scope.pageTitle = <Condition> ? data.products[itemIndex].date : data.products[itemIndex].valuetoday;
}
```

Then if you want to print it.
`<section ng-bind='pageTitle'></section>` use this.